# How do I make sleep in Dyalog APL?

Tags: apl, dyalog

How to implement an analogue of Sleep() function in Dyalog APL?

Task context:

I have a CSV file, and for each line where I call a function, the function makes a network request, and because of their frequency, the server blocks me - I need to pause between each line. But how to implement this pause?

```
 PAIRS
┌───────┬───────┬────────┐
│BTCUSDT│ETHBTC │ETHUSDT │
├───────┼───────┼────────┤
│BTCUSDT│LTCBTC │LTCUSDT │
├───────┼───────┼────────┤
│BTCUSDT│BNBBTC │BNBUSDT │
├───────┼───────┼────────┤
│BTCUSDT│NEOBTC │NEOUSDT │
├───────┼───────┼────────┤

check_buy_buy_sell ⍤1⊢PAIRS
```

I tried googling, didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, try [APLcart](https://aplcart.info?q=sleep) instead of Google…

The answer is `⎕DL` which takes a number of seconds as argument and sleeps for that time. See [the documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/System%20Functions/dl.htm) for details.

Comment: Special thanks for aplcart